# How to create a merchant account in MPGS gateway

Tags: payment, mastercard

I've installed this plugin "Woocommerce" and it supports many payment gateways. It asked me to provide the merchant id of this payment gateway "Mastercard Payment Gateway Services" MPGS! How can I sign up as a merchant in this gateway? I found the api Documents, But I didn't find sign up page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to approach a bank that supports MGPS, to facilitate the creation of a `merchantId` for MPGS

Comment: Do you mean I can't get any MerchantId from MPGS, And they won't work with me and I should to find a bank which supports MPGS and he can give me a new merchantID?

Comment: You can also contact MPGS and they direct you to a bank that can help you